# nestjs e2e testing no logger output

Tags: logging, nestjs, e2e-testing

I am using default built-in logger in NestJS form simple logging during development. But when I run e2e tests there is no logger output on console. A really need this, to see what is happening when test fails.
Snippet from package.json:

`"test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"`

And jest-e2e.json:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "verbose": true
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to overwrite the logger on the chain after `createTestingModule`

```js
const module_: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    ...
})
    .setLogger(new Logger())
    .compile();
```

which is luckily a bit shorter than the method with `app.useLogger`.

This feature was added in https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/6071

As far as I can tell you'll have to do this for every single test setup.

I personally think this is ridiculous. Of course I need my logs when fixing my tests, including debug logs, and I want them without having to add some extra code

Answer (score 5):

I created a my logger that extends ConsoleLogger and nothing changed. But I figured out that I need to tell TestingModule to use it:

```ts
    describe('App (e2e)', () => {
      let app: INestApplication;
    
      beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
          imports: [AppModule],
        }).compile();
    
        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
        app.useLogger(new Logger());
      });
```

Answer (score 4):

[The default testing logger](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/testing/services/testing-logger.service.ts) has no implementation for `log`, `debug`, `warn` or `verbose`. You'd need to pass your own logger to get those logs to show up again. Generally it's to keep the test output clean

Comment: HI Jay, thank you for your answer. But there are logs when unit testing, only during e2e testing, there is no log output. Is TestingLogger provided via DI?....because I don't use it directly, my import is: import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

Comment: When using `Test.createTestingModule()` the testing module's code will use the `TestingLogger` provider via `app.useLogger(new TestingLogger())` and override he original logger